# SQL Merge statement works in Oracle 11g but not 9i

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle9i

I have an SQL MERGE statement working perfectly in Oracle 11g (development environment), but it gives me the following error when I try to run it in Oracle 9i (Production environment): ORA-00905: missing keyword.

Is there any way to make this work in Oracle 9i?  Here is statement:

```
MERGE INTO non_asset dst
   USING (SELECT tag, comments, computer_role
            FROM non_asset_backup
           WHERE sub_group = 'AALVOIP') src
   ON (dst.tag = src.tag)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
         SET dst.comments = src.comments,
             dst.computer_role = src.computer_role
```

Comment: This may help: http://nuijten.blogspot.com/2009/07/delete-in-merge-statement.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 9*i* both the `WHEN MATCHED` and the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` branches were mandatory. In 10*g* and after one of them can be missing (but not both, obviously).
See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/statements_915a.htm#2080942 vs. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm#i2081218

Comment: Hmm, so is there a way I can tell it to do nothing when NOT MATCHED

Comment: To avoid headaches, I would use the same DB version for development as the production.

Comment: BTW, 9i is out of support, so you should upgrade. I know that is not simple, but even 10g is much better in many-many ways, not to mention 11g.

Comment: No, I do not think you can do anything if `NOT MATCHED`. You probably need just `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thanks, you have been very helpful